# HTML heading and html special characters

Tags: html

I'm trying to edit a index.html file but in my heading my html special character code is not showing on the screen.

Example:

```
<h5>Souscrire &#224; infolettre</h5>
```

This should display as "`Souscrire à infolettre`" but the `à` isn't showing.

Comment: Are you saying that the numeric-encoded character displays properly outside of the heading but not in the heading? What shows up in the heading? Are you using a unicode font for your headings?

Comment: No... Its display properly inside of the heading (<h5>Souscrire &#224; infolettre</h5>) but not outside... Like when I look on my web page... And yes i am using a Unicode font. I don't understand why it does that only when i am using heading tags.

Comment: It seems that you are using different fonts for the heading and for the other parts.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: You might be right, but it'd have to be a pretty odd font if it doesn't have "à".  I'd be more inclined to suspect a simple typo (say, `&224;` instead of `&#224;`).

Answer (score 4):

As a french user, you should not do that. Simply encode all your files in UTF-8 and you will be able to use whatever accent you want : ç,é,è,à,ô...

But you will need to add a little header to the html file.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: +1; however, I'd suggest `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` for backwards compatibility with pre-HTML5 user agents.  (Yes, they do still exist.)

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing wrong with your code, as you can see [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xXcDT/).

the problem has to be something else, but to find that out, we'll nee a bit more information:

- which browsers have you tested?
- do other html-entities work?
- have you tried creating a new file only containing that one line?